# Search TextBox without spell check on WP8.0

Tags: windows-phone-8

Windows Phone 8.0 app needs to have a search field - the keyboard should have the search arrow button instead of the default return button. I can get the search keyboard by setting InputScope to "Search", but along with it comes a red wavy line below words that dictionary doesn't contain. Spell check is absolutely not needed in this context - it is in fact very distracting. How do I disable it?

Code to reproduce:

```cs
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <TextBox InputScope="Search" />
</Grid>
```

Steps to reproduce: Run the app, tap on the text box, enter a random search string and press space. The red wavy line will appear underneath the entered text.

[image: TextBox with spell check]

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](http://bsubramanyamraju.blogspot.com/2014/05/windowsphone-store-81-vs-windowsphone-8_4.html) in `Windows Phone 8.1` there's a `property` called `IsSpellCheckEnabled` where you can enable and disable. But this doesn't support for WP8.

Try this within your `TextBlock`:

```
<TextBox SpellCheck.IsEnabled="True" Name="myTextBox"></TextBox>
```

Reference: [SpellCheck.IsEnabled Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.spellcheck.isenabled%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Spell check for 8.1 is well documented by Microsoft and can be easily found with a quick search on Google. My question was about 8.0 though.

Comment: I've had to vote your answer down, because it's obviously not answering the question. It was clearly stated that it's about version 8.0 in both title and the question body.